# Can I repurpose a 2TB Time Capsule as an external drive?

Tags: external-disk, time-capsule

I have an old Time Capsule, 2TB, Model A1355.

Does any way exist to repurpose the device as just an external hard drive?

If possible, I'd like to:

- store my music library on the Time Capsule then access the music via
  iTunes from my MacPro &
- disable the wireless and networking capabilities (excepting any required to use the device as an external drive).

I have upgraded my network/wireless to a Lynksys Velop so I don't need the networking & wireless capabilities of the Time Capsule anymore.

It would just seem like a waste to throw out the device if one can repurpose it.

Comment: Can't you do this through AirPort Utility directly?

Comment: One way would be to repurpose the drive inside the capsule and use another  enclosure.

Comment: First "wireless" *is* networking and second the USB port is for sharing printers and the like. Like @Thunder_Ruler said take the HD out of the Time Capsule and put it in a USB enclosure.

Comment: Bear in mind that A1355 was discontinued in 2011, so the hard drive is at least 9 years old. I would not want to rely on that as a 'media server', even assuming you've got a backup. You can buy a new 2TB USB drive for not much money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does any way exist to repurpose the device as just an external hard drive?

Yes, if you want it **just** to be an external drive. Following this iFixit guide to [Disassembling a Time Capsule](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Airport+Time+Capsule+A1470+Hard+Drive+Replacement/61924).

You can remove the internal Hard Drive and place it into a dedicated USB external drive enclosure.

As far as I am aware, you cannot disable the core functionality without also disabling access to the drive.